# Monitioring Locks

Tags: sql-server, locks

We are using Livelink for our records management and if a user moves a folder with lost of sub folders it presents a lock on the database and slows the whole system down. Dispite sending many warnings out to users this is still happening. Is there any sort or monitoring tool that will give us a an early warning system as to when the locks occur?

If not what code would I use to run to show locks and to present with the username of who is causing the locks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what Livelink is and I have no clue what documents, folders and movements you're talking about. That being said, since you mention locks and you tagged your question SQL Server: in a SQL Server system lock contention can be greatly reduced by deploying snapshot isolation models, see [Using Snapshot Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28VS.80%29.aspx). So simply enable read_committed snapshot and this will unblock any read performed under the default, read committed, isolation level:

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```